# DQL using ON with WITH clause

Tags: mysql, sql, dql

Hello i have this query:

```
SELECT y
FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y
LEFT JOIN y.allViews v WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
GROUP BY y
```

it works fine, but i am attempting to add a filter:

```
AND y.type = :videoType
```

How can i add it to this query? It does not work properly if i add it after:

```
BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
```

It ends up being a part of the BETWEEN statement, and i do not want it to be part of it, it should be "Above" or well have higher priority then the BETWEEN clause, can i somehow ad a ON before the with or what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT y
FROM YTScraperBundle:YouTubeVideo y
LEFT JOIN y.allViews v WITH v.firstFetch BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate
WHERE y.type = :videoType
GROUP BY y
```

It's not part of the JOIN, which is what you were making it. The alternative is to put it in the WHERE clause.